# Git: How to go back one and make a fix without losing current work?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to make a small fix to a release but I already (stupidly) stayed on my master and made a commit that I don't want to lose.

I'm guessing that I should make my current spot a new branch, go back to release commit, fix it, save that commit, and then go to the newly made branch and merge it all.

And, of course, I have NO idea how to do that.

Or is stash better for something like this?

Help? Thank you.

Comment: if you did a commit then stash won't work

Comment: have you pushed your updates to the master branch to any remotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a branch from your current work: `git checkout -b new_branch`. Then go back to master: `git checkout master`. Then, from master, reset to one commit back: `git reset --hard HEAD~` (You could put a number after the ~ to specify a number of commits, but no number means 1 commit.) Then `master` will be back one commit, and `new_branch` will have your new work. Look at `git log` on both branches to verify.

If you want to bring the `new_branch` work in again later, from `master`, do `git merge new_branch`.

Comment: This is correct ONLY if you haven't already pushed the changes you added to master to a remote. If you have already pushed, this will cause problem for everyone else using the problems.

Comment: Thanks. That worked well...except for some conflicts, but I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), and use the `edit` command to make the fix you want in the  commit. So, it's like you never did that mistake.

Type `git rebase -i <release-commit-hash>`.

Default editor opens (maybe Vim); for the , select `edit` command.

Fix the files you need, then add them with `git add .`.
Then, amend the with `git commit --amend`.
Last, type `git rebase --continue` to go on.